# Postman gives java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception error when hitting the api second time on same token

Tags: spring-boot, indexoutofboundsexception

When I generate new token and hit the api, it rusn successfully but when i hit the api second time on same token it gives me

```
    "code": "0101",
    "status": "Fail",
    "message": "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException",
    "data": {
        "code": null,
        "status": null,
        "message": null,
        "errors": null,
        "info": null
    }
}
```

The api which i am hitting is a test api

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getAllLeadsOne() {
        return new String("Hello");
    }
```

I am unable to understand the issue. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please post your security filterChain code or your token parser mechanism code.
from your question its hard to determine the exact reason.

Comment: Thank you so much. But my issue got resolved